# Getting error, `Prop `className` did not match` when deploying to Heroku, but works locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm getting the following error:

> Prop `className` did not match. Server: "jss1 jss5" Client: "makeStyles-root-1 makeStyles-root-5"

When deploying to *Heroku*. Everything works fine normally locally, but not when deployed. I pretty much have the same setup as [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/ssr-with-next-js-styled-components-and-material-ui-b1e88ac11dfa).

I've found a similar [Github issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18018), but none of the suggestions there helped me.

Locally, these classes similar to `makeStyles-${key}-${id}` are injected when I'm developing, but it's not working on Heroku. What could be going wrong?

## Edit

---

After more investigation, it seems that setting NODE_ENV to production is why it's breaking. Here are my scripts in `package.json`:

```json
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "nodemon server.ts",
        "build": "next build && tsc --project tsconfig.server.json",
        "start": "NODE_ENV=production node .next/production-server/server.js"
    }
```

If I change it to:

```json
    ...
        "start": "NODE_ENV=development node .next/production-server/server.js"
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
    ...
```

Then it works the same way as it would work if I were to run `npm run dev`.

I've noticed that when `NODE_ENV=production`, all my Material UI components that use `makeStyles` have classNames of `jss-'some-number'`. Some are `jss1`, `jss5`, etc. When `NODE_ENV=development`, these get replaces with `makeStyles-root-1`, `makeStyles-footer-1`, etc.

My `tsconfig.server.json`:

```json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmit": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": ".next/production-server/"
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

It seems that this isn't related to Heroku at all, and there's something wrong with my configuration. Any help would be much appreciated.

---

[Re-production issue](https://github.com/mkhoussid/nextjs-mui)

[Github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/16748) issue with a reproducible repo.

Comment: Looks like styled components aren't handled properly during SSR. I'd suggest to double check the setup: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/ssr-with-next-js-styled-components-and-material-ui-b1e88ac11dfa#6ba9

Comment: This issue is specific to Material UI, not `styled-components`

Comment: Material UI is just a UI. My guess: `styled-components` attaches class names to the DOM nodes. SSR is enabled in production and it injects `jss` instead of proper class names. So there must be an issue in SSR + `styled-components` setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `server.ts`, you are checking an incorrect environment variable to determine whether you are running in production mode.
Change the line

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_DEV !== 'production';
```

to

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
```

Comment: It is in the Github project referenced at the end of the question.

Comment: @Mike K Since you already marked this as a solution on Github, why not mark it here as well and award the bounty. Instead of making other people investigate more just to find out it's been solved already.

Comment: For sure. I wasn't able to award the bounty at the time, there was a time limit

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in your [`package.json`](https://github.com/mkhoussid/nextjs-mui/blob/master/package.json) on the line number **8** you have this script:

```
"start": "NODE_ENV=production node .next/production-server/server.js"
```

That means the `NODE_ENV` variable is `production`, so in the whole the project for checking *development* or *production* environment you should check the `NODE_ENV` key but in your [`server.ts`](https://github.com/mkhoussid/nextjs-mui/blob/master/server.ts) file on line number **6** the following code is seen:

```js
const dev = process.env.NODE_DEV !== 'production';
```

That means you are checking the `NODE_DEV` environment variable and it is different from the `NODE_ENV` environment variable, because of this mismatching you have the current issue.

**Solution**: check a consistent environment variable for production.